# How to write test for dataSource.getPooledConnection()

Tags: java, mysql, database, junit

I have a class and that uses database pool connection. My problem is how can I write the test case for the same please help with an example

I am using this in my class

```
MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
dataSource.setURL("dbc:mysql://localhost:3306/unittest");
dataSource.setUser("root");
dataSource.setPassword("root123");
PooledConnection pconn;
pconn = dataSource.getPooledConnection();
```

I can test for dataSource.getPooledConnection()

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to test the connection pool. It comes from a supplier. A major supplier. They test it. You need to test what you are doing with the connection. If the test discloses an apparent problem with the supplier's code, you refine to to a test case that demonstrates the problem, and you submit a bug report to the supplier.